# auth0 login issue “We’re sorry, something went wrong when attempting to log in.” error 403 Invalid State

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

On my iOS app that is using [Auth0.swift](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.swift) library

I see this error trying to authenticate the user.
“We’re sorry, something went wrong when attempting to log in.”

The application is asking the authentication in the following way

```
Auth0
    .webAuth()
    .scope("openid profile email offline_access")
    .audience("https://api.xxx.xxx")
    .start
```

Debugging the Safary login page when the request is performed

```
Request 
:method: POST 
:scheme: https 
:authority: XXX.eu.auth0.com 
:path: /usernamepassword/login 
Content-Type: application/json 
Accept: / Host: XXX.eu.auth0.com 
Accept-Language: en-us 
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate 
Origin: https://XXX.eu.auth0.com 
Referer: https://XXX.eu.auth0.com/login?state=IqUcaKz8oL43BPVflsm84gUET1cDrnaN&client=XXXmyclientIDXXX&protocol=oauth2&response_type=code&redirect_uri=xxx.XXX%3A%2F%2FXXX.eu.auth0.com%2Fios%2Fxxx.XXX%2Fcallback&audience=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.XXX.xxx&code_challenge=U89LGQB5BSIi5ilLyQqSTVqjrqYDwn9O700SrC-70tk&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access&auth0Client=xxx 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 DNT: 1 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 722 
Auth0-Client: xxx
```

I see the following error response

```
    { "statusCode": 403, 
"description": "Invalid state", 
"name": "AnomalyDetected", 
"code": "access_denied" }
```

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce it anymore in my debug environment but the problem is still present in the field for some users.
I suspect that it could be related to the iOS 12 update.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If you have any tips I would really appreciate it...

Answer (score -1):

With Error `name": "AnomalyDetected", "code": "access_denied"` . Are you sure you don't have anomaly detection turned ON and had several failed login attempt from same IP?

Comment: I can confirm that we are using the brute-force protection but not the breached-password protection and it is set in this way since long time ago but the issue starts to happen just from a week.

I see that the error is related to “Anomaly Detection” but the error looks different from the “blocked user” error and we do not see any issue notified on the users account involved on this login problem.